# Add existing Pivot tables to data model

Tags: excel, model, connection, pivot

In Excel 2013, I have one table "Table1" in worksheet "Data" and I have a dozen pivot tables in another worksheet named "PivotTable". When I created the pivot tables I was unaware of the checkbox "Add this data to the data model". Is there a way to add all my existing pivot tables to the data model after-the-fact?

Answer (score 11):

If you go to the existing pivot table, below the list of fields you have available, there should be a line that says `More Tables...`. Click on that and it'll remake your pivot table in a new tab with that data model option checked. You do lose your number formatting, but it sure beats remaking the whole stupid thing!

Comment: Answer still valid in Office 365